# OpenGL window with SDL not showing

Tags: c, linux, opengl, graphics, sdl

I'm working on a program with OpenGL/SDL, but the window won't draw. The window's entry appears in the taskbar and the alt+tab menu, but no thumbnail is shown. When I click it, it's marked as active, but nothing changes onscreen.

I can verify that `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` and `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()` are being called from my render loop, and that `SDL_SetVideoMode` is succeeding, but it still won't render. It's not a shared library issue, since other SDL/GL apps work fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's the graphics initialization:

```
void GraphicsManager::initGraphics() {
    // Access prefs
    PreferencesManager* prefMgr = PreferencesManager::getInstance();
    int width = prefMgr->getIntKey("res_width");
    int height = prefMgr->getIntKey("res_height");

    if(SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize SDL video!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);

    m_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 0, SDL_OPENGL);
    if(!m_screen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid screen pointer\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);

    // Setup OpenGL stuffs
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // We're only using 2D
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glViewport(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, width, height, 0.0, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    // Init FPS stuff
    m_avgFps = 60.0f;
    m_lastUpdate = SDL_GetTicks();
}
```

Here's my main loop:

```
while(stateMgr->getState() != GS_QUIT) {
    // Process input events
    inputMgr->processEvents();

    // Update the current system mode
    stateMgr->update();

    // Update GUI state
    guiMgr->update();

    // Render
    gfxMgr->render();
    //char buf[16];
    //snprintf(buf, 16, "FPS: %4.2f", gfxMgr->getFramerate());
    //testWindow->getChild("TestRoot/Framerate")->setText(buf);
    SDL_Delay(10);
}
```

And here's the render function:

```
void GraphicsManager::render() {
    std::list<IRenderCallback*>::iterator rci;

    // Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Run render callbacks
    /*for(rci=m_renderCallbacks.begin();rci != m_renderCallbacks.end();rci++) {
        (*rci)->preRender();
    }

    // Iterate through all renderables and render them
    std::list<Renderable*>::iterator i;
    for(i=m_renderables.begin();i != m_renderables.end();i++) {
        (*i)->render();
    }

    // Run render callbacks
    for(rci=m_renderCallbacks.begin();rci != m_renderCallbacks.end();rci++) {
        (*rci)->preFlip();
    }*/

    // Flip the buffers
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    // Update FPS stuff
    Uint32 now = SDL_GetTicks();
    Uint32 timeTaken = now - m_lastUpdate;
    m_lastUpdate = now;
    double seconds = (double)timeTaken / 1000.0f;
    m_avgFps = (1.0f / seconds);

    // Run render callbacks
    for(rci=m_renderCallbacks.begin();rci != m_renderCallbacks.end();rci++) {
        (*rci)->postRender();
    }
}
```

Comment: In particular, your window creation and your main loop.

Comment: Okay, I added the main loop, render code, and render initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down.  Do the (mostly-ish) simplest thing that should work:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if(SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize SDL video!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    SDL_Surface* m_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 0, SDL_OPENGL);
    if(!m_screen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid screen pointer\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    cout << "GL_VERSION  : " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
    cout << "GL_VENDOR   : " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << endl;
    cout << "GL_RENDERER : " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << endl;

    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);

    // Setup OpenGL stuffs
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // We're only using 2D
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glViewport(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, width, height, 0.0, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    float angle = 0;
    bool running = true;
    while( running )
    {
        // handle all pending events
        SDL_Event event;
        while( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:  
                running = false; 
                break;
            default:        
                break;
            }
        }

        angle += 1;
        while( angle > 360 )
            angle -= 360;

        // Render
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef( width/2, height/2, 0 );
        glScalef( 150, 150, 0 );

        glRotatef( angle, 0, 0, 1 );
        glColor3ub(255,0,0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2i(0,0);
        glVertex2i(1,0);
        glVertex2i(1,1);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();

        // Flip the buffers
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

        SDL_Delay(10);
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

If that works all you have to do (ha!) is figure out how the simple program execution flow differs from your large program.  If it doesn't work your environment is probably goofed somehow.

What do the `GL_VERSION/VENDOR/RENDERER` checks print on your system?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting your bits per pixel to 0.

```
m_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 0, SDL_OPENGL);
```

Generally I think you want 32 in your case.

With that said, if that doesn't fix your problem, try calling:

```
m_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 0, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER);
```

That will request a hardware surface and double-buffering.

I also didn't see you call this:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

before your first call to glLoadIdentity. You may have done this in the past - however, SDL_SetVideoMode can cause the GL context to be reset, which makes it good practice to re-setup all OpenGL parameters that you need to.

There is one bigger concern, however. We are focusing on your GL code, but it's possible SDL got mucked up before (or after) this subsystem initialized. **I would like to suggest that you put in a call to SDL_GetError() once before you enter your main loop just to see that some error you didn't check for way back hasn't interfered.**

There are quite a number of more things that SDL can be finicky about when using OpenGL. My next concern is that your code flow may be calling the get_surface more than once...try adding a static variable to the function like so:

```
static int has_init = 0;

has_init++;
if (has_init > 1) {
    // Well that's odd isn't it
}
```